# How can I sync non-google docs with google drive automatically?

Tags: excel, documentation, synchronization, google-drive-api

I know google drive has a sync folder now and that most office documents placed within that folder will sync automatically with google drive.  However, in order to edit, for example, an excel spreadsheet that has been synched to google drive, I have to convert it to a google doc.  That means that any edits I make to the original excel file on my desktop will not sync with the newly created google doc.  Is there any app or something that I can use that can sync changes made to an excel file on my desktop (I am using a Mac) to its google doc counterpart in google drive and vice versa??  I'd still like to do most of my edits using the Office software when possible...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't.

You'll need to use a different cloud service, or don't convert them to Google docs if you want to use office software. Office software and Google cloud are competing products that do not have direct compatibility.